# Vim, highlight repeated words

Tags: text-editing, documents

When writing a technical document (papers, blueprints...) it's very likely to repeat a keyword, and a lot of time is wasted in trying to replace repetitions with synonyms.

A very helpful tool in this case could be an editor extension that highlights frequently repeated words, better if more and more markedly as ther usage frequency is high (except for extremely frequent words, like conjunctions).

Is there some software product like this? I would prefer vim extensions (as this is my editor of choice) but the functionality is general enough, so any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score -1):

You need StyleChecker vim plugin

Comment: kindly elaborate with little explanation about the plugin to make answer perfect,additionally mention link for stylechecker